# Angular JS global config for resource success query

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, angularjs-resource

I have implemented resources in my single page angular app which fires to my REST client server. I have made different services for each resource. Now my REST server is sending a value in response header, now I want to know a proper way where I can retrieve that value from headers.

My service code:

```
app.service('$job', function($resource) {
    var job = $resource(service_base_url+'jobs.json/:id');
    return job;
});
```

My controller which is getting headers:

```
app.controllerProvider.register('JobPostsController',['$scope','$job', function($scope, $job) {
    $scope.jobs = {};
    $scope.job_titles = {};
    $job.query(function(jobs,responseHeaders){
        var headers = responseHeaders();
        some_function(headers.user);
        $scope.jobs = jobs.jobs;
    });
}
]);
```

I am getting headers in my above code, but I don't want to inject it in all controllers. So is there a proper way to do it? Some single config code which will run for all future resources request or some kind of event which can be only triggered when successful resource response with 200 OK

Comment: Have you tried to set up the call in a run block ?

Comment: no whats that? I am new to angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

I don't know exactly your logic. You could register a global interceptor which intercepts all requests:

```
angular.module('App', [])
       .config(function ($httpProvider){
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
             return {
                   'response': function(response) {
                        var headers = response.headers();
                        some_function(headers.user);
                        return response;
                    }
             };
           });
       });
```

or just register an interceptor which **runs only for all requests of this query**.

```
app.service('$job', function($resource) {
    var job = $resource(service_base_url+'jobs.json/:id',{}, {
             'query': {
                         method:'GET', 
                         isArray:true,
                         interceptor: {
                              'response': function(response) {
                                      var headers = response.headers();
                                      some_function(headers.user);
                                      return response;
                               }
                          }
                      }
    });
    return job;
});
```

**Side notes:**

- Should not use `$` prefix for your service name as it's reserved for angular, it may conflict with angular future versions.
- I guess you need `.factory` instead of `.service`

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the service in a run block like:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .run(['$rootScope',  '$job',function ($rootScope, $job) {
        $rootScope.jobs = {};
        $rootScope.job_titles = {};
        $job.query(function(jobs,responseHeaders){
            var headers = responseHeaders();
            some_function(headers.user);
            $rootScope.jobs = jobs.jobs;
        });  

    }]);
```

The only drawback your service is global to the app

Comment: I cant use this because I have almost 20 services, and I cannot inject same code, will interceptors work here?

Comment: @ntechi: This is only run `once` when the app starts, it does not run again every time we issue a request.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a base service factory. This would allow you to have common service related functionality in one place

```
app.factory('ServiceBase', function () {
    function ServiceBase() {
      this.responseHeaders = function responseHeaders(resp){
         // todo
      };
    }
    return ServiceBase;
});

app.service('$job', function($resource, ServiceBase) {
  var service = function () {
    // $job related functions here
  };

  angular.extend(service, new ServiceBase());
  return service;
});
```

Now anything in the ServiceBase is accessible to the controller and to the service. This allows you to have common functionality, has no new injection dependencies (on the controller), and is easy to extend further.

Answer (score -1):

I think angulrjs response interceptors can help u for this.